# TCP Connection - keep same connection between same client requests

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Im trying to code a login and register service for a school project.
I have this working if I create a new connection to the server on each request.

What i want is to keep the same connection for when I do the login.

Server part with the response:

```
    try{
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Server Error: " + e);
    }
    while(true) { 
        try{    
            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept(); 
            System.out.println(connectionSocket.toString());
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream())); 

            clientRequest = inFromClient.readLine().split(" ");
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Server Error: " + e);
        }
   }





public static void sendResponse(String response){

    try{
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());    
        outToClient.writeBytes(response);
        connectionSocket.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Connection Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Cliente side:

```
inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while(true){
            System.out.print("\nCommand: ");
            try{
                command = inFromUser.readLine();

                clientSocket = new Socket(hostname,port);
                outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


                outToServer.writeBytes(command + '\n');                 
                serverResponse = inFromServer.readLine();                   
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + serverResponse);



            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Client Error - " + e.getMessage());
            }               
    }
```

This works well like this, creating new connection everytime.
Now if i only create new socket on client side when the socket is null and don't close the connectionSocket on server side, it sends a message to server but never gets a response from server until the connectionSocket is closed.

Anyone have any idea why or an idea to make it work on a single connection?
Been reading a lot about this and can t figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stepping it through in a debugger? Your problem is you hang in ServerSocket.Accept() after reading one line. You'll have to split connection accepting and handling it into separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP is connectionless:** The HTTP client ie. browser initiates an HTTP request and after a request is made, 
the client disconnects from the server and waits for a response. The server process the request and re-establish 
the connection with the client to send response back.

HTTP/1.0 uses a new connection for each request/response exchange where as HTTP/1.1 connection may be used 
for one or more request/response exchanges.

Comment: so HTTP/1.1 is persistent.How I can i use it instead? I really need a persistent connection in order to work with logins and logged-in-only-commands.

Comment: @IvanFreire What do you want to achieve? Do you have some application protocol? What is your application doing in the first place and what will be communicated via those connections?

Comment: This is a kind of twitter. First you have to register a user wich works fine like this because it can create a new connection for each register. But then it needs to login aswell. With login i must keep the connection up to send messages to other logged in users and check messages sent from other users. 

I was reading your other comment trying to understand how multi-threading works.

Comment: @IvanFreire So in your approach, only logged-in users can "talk" to each other. So it is more like an online-chat than twitter. You will miss all messages sent, while you are offline ...

Comment: well this is just a school project not an actual app :p But to achieve this i really need to keep my users connected to the server and not closing the connection after each request.